# undo permanent rewrite rule Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, url-rewriting

Ok I'm extremely noob to nginx and did something very stupid. I wrote the following code in my sites available file. Deleting it doesn't seem to undo it.

```
location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {  
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /?page=$1 last;  
    rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;  
}
```

I wrote this before I fully understood what it meant and since have removed it from my configuration file. Despite removing this it looks like it is still effecting one page of my website. I have tried different browsers other than the one that I loaded this page on when the rule was applied and it is still not serving the images correctly.

How can I undo this?

The site is not yet public so I'm not worried about other people's browsers catches still redirecting after this issue is resolved.

Is there a place in my server that is continuing to redirect despite the rule no longer in my sites-available and sites-enabled folder? It is a linux/ubuntu server and so far this is the first site that this server is running.

Thank you for any help or ideas on how to solve this!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [rfc2616 section 10.3.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) about http status 301

> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any
>   future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned
>   URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically
>   re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new
>   references returned by the server, where possible. This response is
>   cacheable unless indicated otherwise.

A lot of browsers use that to cache the response locally, so that it doesn't waste another request when calling the same URL, unlike `302` which redirects but doesn't cache.
To solve this you just need to clear the local cache, and not even the whole cache, if you did this today you could just clear today's cache and every thing will be back to normal.

Comment: I opened the url in Incognito mode in my browser and got everything as I excpeted. As @Mohammad AbuShady said

Answer (score 0):

If you have add this location block to your/one of your site conf in nginx/sites-available and thereafter symlinked the file to nginx/sites-enabled, it can only be in the nginx/sites-available/site.

However if you copied /nginx/sites-available/site to nginx/sites-enabled/site you also have to delete the file in sites-enabled...

To be sure, did you reload nginx after deleting configuration ?

Comment: Thanks for answering.  The confusing part is that I did check the sites-enabled and it is not there.  The sites-available and enabled are symlinked.  And I have reloaded nginx.  And even more confusing it seems to be only effecting the page that I ran in the browser when I had the rewrite rule in place. It is adding a / and breaking all the png and js files.  All the other pages on the site are working fine.  Could the rewrite rule be cached somewhere else on my server?  Thanks again!

Comment: Can you provide your site nginx config file ?

Comment: I don't see how the rewrite rule could be cached somewhere unless you put it in nginx/nginx.conf. You can try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: `server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
 server_name mywebsite.com;

 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 index index.html index.htm;

 # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
 server_name localhost;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off; 
}`

Comment: The above is my config file in my sites available folder.  At this time it is the only config file I have.  Despite removing the bad code, restarting nginx, and trying the site from other computers with fresh browsers the page is still changing the path.  Worst case scenario.  I can just rename the page.  It is more frustrating not knowing why it is still causing these issues.  Thank you for your thoughts on this.

Comment: This seems crazy. After clearing cache if nothing change that's weird. You say it only affects one page ? Not all .* files designate by the location ? 
Would it be possible that you have a .htaccess file and that Apache is doing some rewriting instead of Nginx? I see that your nginx config does not have a deny location for .ht files

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The thing is I have no .htaccess files in any of my folders.  After a few days of trying to track down the error, I need to just do the easy work around of renaming the page.  Thanks for lending a hand.